# free cd ripper software on windows

Tags: audio, ripping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good, free audio CD ripping/extraction tools exist for Windows, and supporting multiple formats?](https://superuser.com/questions/2100/what-good-free-audio-cd-ripping-extraction-tools-exist-for-windows-and-supporti)

I am looking to find a cd ripper software package that is free for windows. I am looking to rip audio. It can be in .wave or mp3 format

Answer (score 5):

I use the built in Windows Media Player to rip my CDs to MP3.

Comment: Here is the official documentation: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-xp/help/windows-media-player/11/rip-a-cd

Answer (score 1):

[FreeRip](http://www.freerip.com/)

FreeRIP is an advanced CD to MP3 Converter that comes packed with features. At its core, FreeRIP reads audio from your CDs and allows you to save them to your coumputer in a variety of digital formats including WMA, MP3, Ogg, Wav, or FLAC audio files

Comment: FreeRip works.  Maybe next time write your own description though, instead of copy/pasting straight from their website.

Comment: @JNK This is what I do every time I recommend software, especially if I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @steve.lippert - I think if you are recommending software you haven't used, quoting the marketing materials is the opposite of what you should do, since it gives the user the impression you are endorsing it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using Windows: If you are looking for third party software (not built-in), I would recommend [BonkEnc](http://www.bonkenc.org/).

> BonkEnc is a free audio converter and
>   CD ripper with support for various
>   popular formats and encoders. It
>   currently converts between MP3,
>   MP4/M4A, WMA, Ogg Vorbis, FLAC, AAC,
>   WAV and Bonk formats.
>
> With BonkEnc you easily rip your audio
>   CDs to MP3 or WMA files for use with
>   your hardware player or convert files
>   that do not play with other audio
>   software. You can even convert whole
>   music libraries retaining the folder
>   and filename structure.
>
> The integrated CD ripper supports the
>   CDDB/freedb online CD database. It
>   will automatically query song
>   information and write it to ID3v2 or
>   other title information tags.

There's even a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/bonkenc_portable).